# Consume RabbitMQ and Emit to Socket IO

Tags: python, websocket, socket.io, rabbitmq, pika

I'm working on a python project where i have to consume messages from a rabbitmq queue and emit to a socketio channel. I'm using pika and pika is blocking. So im not able to perform message consuming and socket emit simultaneously. Is there any way around this ?

Comment: The typical pika workflow is that it blocks until a message can be retrieved, at which point the function you supplied to it as a callback processes it (and in this case sends it on). If you need to send out messages asynchronously, you'll need to use another thread.

Comment: Can you point me to any tutorials or examples ?

Comment: Tutorials or examples of what? Using pika or using threads? Here's the [RabbitMQ's tutorial using pika](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-one-python.html). Here's a [tutorial for using threading](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_multithreading.htm).

Comment: Is this for RPC? Maybe something like this could work https://github.com/eandersson/python-rabbitmq-examples/blob/master/Flask-examples/

Comment: thanks @eandersson. This is what i've been working on.